# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4096 into shape (64,64,3)

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, conv-neural-network, reshape

Hi stack overflow friends :)
I trained a CNN model for predicting number images.
Learned it successfully And I want to predict a number from an image in which several numbers.
But I got an error.
I'll show you my dataset and some of my code.

**Dataset.py**

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 64
img_width = 64  

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
data_dir,
validation_split=0.2,
subset="training",
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size)
```

**Model.py**

```
num_classes = 10

model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Predict Several Numbers.py**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

img_color = cv.imread('mypath/test.PNG', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_color, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,img_binary = cv.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement( cv.MORPH_RECT, ( 5, 5 ) )
img_binary = cv.morphologyEx(img_binary, cv. MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(img_binary, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                    cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(contour)
    length = max(w, h) + 60
    img_digit = np.zeros((length, length, 1),np.uint8)
    new_x,new_y = x-(length - w)//2, y-(length - h)//2
    img_digit = img_binary[new_y:new_y+length, new_x:new_x+length]

    model = load_model('mypath/saved_model.h5')

    img_digit = cv.resize(img_digit,(64,64), interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

    img_digit = img_digit / 255.0

    img_input = np.array(img_digit).reshape(-1,64,64,3)

    predictions = model.predict(img_input)
    number = np.argmax(predictions)
    print(number)

    cv.rectangle(img_color, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 0), 2)

    location = (x + int(w *0.5), y - 10)
    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX  
    fontScale = 1.2
    cv.putText(img_color, str(number), location, font, fontScale, (0,255,0), 2)


    cv.imshow('digit', img_digit)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

I think it's the perfect code. but I got error :(

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4096 into shape (64,64,3)

Why I getting this error? Help me!!!

Comment: Where are you getting the error? How did you build the CNN? What shape had your training images? This is hardly a minimum reproducible example, your code doesn’t have comments... under these sad circumstances debugging is just a guess game. My guess is that `img_digit` is the problem. Somewhere you reshaped that (64x64) image into a (4,096) plain array. Use a debugger to trace the problem.

Comment: getting error Predict Several Numbers.py's img_input = np.array(img_digit).reshape(-1,64,64,3) .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are declaring im_digit to be 2D array but reshaping it to 3D (3 channels). Also note that your img_binary is also single channel (2D) image. All that you need to change is to keep working with gray scale:

```
img_input = np.array(img_digit).reshape(1,64,64,1)
```

This answer however assumes that you have trained your model using a 64x64 input.